# Kivy scrollview with screenmanager and gridlayout

Tags: python, kivy

Like many other questions, im having issues with scrollview.
I'm trying to have a bunch of different buttons, that goes to different screens, but the buttons sit on top of each other, are stuck in the corner or only one button is appearing and the screen is cut in half.

I've tried having the screenmanager outside the TabbedPanelItem, giving every widget a size and no size_hint_y but to no avail? is it not possible to have the screenmanager inside the tabbedpanel or is it bad practice

**Python file.**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen 
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.lang import Builder
Config.set('graphics', 'resizeable', 0)
Window.size = (375,700)

class MainScreen(Screen):
    pass
class FirstScreen(Screen):
    pass

class SecondScreen(Screen):
    pass
root = Builder.load_file("main.kv")
class myapp(App):
    def build(self):
        return root

if __name__ == '__main__':
    myapp().run()
```

**main.kv**

```
TabbedPanel:
    do_default_tab: False

    TabbedPanelItem:
        text:"1"
        ScrollView:
            size: self.size
            FloatLayout: #gridlayout? #boxlayout?
                size_hint_y: None
                ScreenManager:
                    id: manager  

                    MainScreen:
                        name: 'main'

                        GridLayout:
                            spacing: 10
                            padding: 10
                            cols:1
                            row_default_height: 100
                            row_force_default: True
                            Button:
                                text: 'first'
                                on_press: manager.current = 'first'  
                                size_hint: 1, None
                                height: 100
                            Button:
                                text: 'Second'
                                on_press: manager.current = 'second'  
                                
                    FirstScreen:
                        name: 'first'
                    SecondScreen:
                        name: "second"
    TabbedPanelItem:
        text:"2"

    TabbedPanelItem:
        text:"3"
<FirstScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        Label:
            text:"first"
        Button:
            text: 'Back to main'
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'main'

<SecondScreen>
    BoxLayout:
        Label:
            text:"second"
        Button:
            text: 'Back to main'
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'main'
```

Comment: Just as a quick comment, it's not a bad practice to nest the ScreenManager inside another widget, it's just a widget like any other, and it can be useful to use it in a small part of the screen, or even in a widget that is not always visible, like a TabbedPanel indeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do what you want, but it seems a bit complicated. Here is a `kv` that I think will do it:

```
TabbedPanel:
    do_default_tab: False

    TabbedPanelItem:
        text:"1"
        ScrollView:
            ScreenManager:
                id: manager  
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.current_screen.height  # only seems to work for first Screen
                on_current_screen: self.height = self.current_screen.height  # required because above line failure

                MainScreen:
                    name: 'main'
                    size_hint_y: None
                    height: grid.height  # set this Screen height to the height of the GridLayout

                    GridLayout:
                        id: grid
                        size_hint_y: None
                        height: self.minimum_height  # set this height to the minimum required
                        spacing: 10
                        padding: 10
                        cols:1
                        row_default_height: 100
                        row_force_default: True
                        Button:
                            text: 'first'
                            on_press: manager.current = 'first'  
                            size_hint: 1, None
                            height: 100
                        Button:
                            text: 'Second'
                            on_press: manager.current = 'second'  
                            
                FirstScreen:
                    name: 'first'
                SecondScreen:
                    name: "second"
    TabbedPanelItem:
        text:"2"

    TabbedPanelItem:
        text:"3"
<FirstScreen>:
    size_hint_y: None
    height: 100   # must set its height
    BoxLayout:
        Label:
            text:"first"
        Button:
            text: 'Back to main'
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'main'

<SecondScreen>
    size_hint_y: None
    height: 100   # must set its height
    BoxLayout:
        Label:
            text:"second"
        Button:
            text: 'Back to main'
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'main'
```

A few things to note:

- You don't need a `Layout` to contain the `ScreenManager`.
- You need to set the height of the `ScreenManager` based on the height of its current `Screen`.
- The line `height: self.current_screen.height` should adjust the height of the `ScreenManager` every time the current `Screen` changes, but it doesn't. So I added `on_current_screen: self.height = self.current_screen.height` to adjust the size when the current `Screen` changes.
- Since the `ScreenManager` height depends on the `Screen` height, every `Screen` must have a well defined height.
- The `MainScreen` height is determined by the `GridLayout` height, and the `GridLayout` height is calculated using `self.minimum_height`.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help with the scrollview, works perfect. you have been very helpful. And thank you very much for teaching me through the notes. its very kind of you